# How to use GeometryProxy outside of a ViewBuilder?

Tags: swift, swiftui, geometryreader

I implemented a *BasicContainer* upon `GeometryReader` with the functionality of a `@ViewBuilder`. How can I use this *inside* `GeometryProxy`, **outside** when declaring the content?

Here is my BasicContainer:

```
struct BasicContainer<Content : View> : View {
    
    let content : Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            content
                .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.3, height: 200)
                // do some other fancy stuff ...       
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, when I use the `BasicContainer` as it's meant to be:

```
struct ContentView: View { 
    var body: some View {
        BasicContainer {
            Text("Roberts BasicContainer")
        }
    }
}
```

But what, if I would like to have the GeometryProxy also **outside**, (like Apple implemented their `GeometryReader`), like so:

```
BasicContainer { outsideGeo in 
         Text("Width: \(outsideGeo.size.width)")
}
```

I guess some kind of a `@Binding` could make the trick, but so far I couldn't make it work.
Is this even possible to *realize*?

**Any help is very appreciated !!!**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
let content : (GeometryProxy) -> Content

init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (GeometryProxy) -> Content) {
    self.content = content
}
```

then:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
        content(proxy)
            .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.3, height: 200)
            // do some other fancy stuff ...       
    }
```

edit: I assumed your geometryproxy is named proxy. -> Explicit implementation to avoid confusion.

when you call your container you can do:

```
BasicContainer { outsideGeo in 
     Text("Width: \(outsideGeo.size.width)")
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: added explicit implementation. And some typos as i was not on my mac